# Dynamic Select com query

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, query

Quero fazer um formulario dinamico igual a este:
https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/Techniques/working-examples/SCR19/dynselect.html

Estou a ter dificuldades em interligar mysql, php e javascript na seguinte medida:
-O primeiro select as options values são geradas por uma query (Select * from Continent)

-Conforme o Continent selecionado gera automaticamente as opções do Country select fazendo a consulta (Select * from Country where id_continent="id")

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser utilizado um .getJSON() no seu javascript e retonar uma lista com as opções dos paises ...

```
$.getJSON("SelecionarPaises.php", data : idcontinente).done(function (paises) {
// vai receber uma lista de paises aqui, ai pode adicionar onde quiser
});
```